# Sending a byte[] to the GPU?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, gpgpu, hlsl

I'm using unity, and I wanna send a byte array to the GPU using HLSL. I know about the ByteAddressBuffer, but I have no idea how to use it. I kinda just want to know how to send "byte"s to the GPU. I want to have a `StructuredBuffer<byte>` in my compute shader.

Comment: Why did I get too much down-votes??? Is there anything I missed?

Comment: Your question doesn't really show that/what you have tried to solve your problem. (I think that's why)

Comment: This question is completely legitimate. Wondering about so many downvotes.

Comment: I agree, fair question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the shader part, you can use a `StructuredBuffer`. I don't know exactly if there is the byte data type in HLSL, so I will just use integers for this example.

Shader code:

```
Shader "Name" {
    SubShader {
        ...
        StructuredBuffer<int> _Data;
        ...
    }
}
```

On the C# side, you have a Material that corresponds to your shader, lets call it `mat`, and your byte array `bArr`. Additionally you have to create a gpu buffer, that you can then bind to your shader: `ComputeBuffer dataBuf = new ComputeBuffer(bArr.Length, sizeof(int))`.

Finally, load your array onto the gpu `dataBuf.SetData(bArr)` and bind the buffer to your shader `mat.SetBuffer("_Data", dataBuf);`

**Edit**

> I want to have a StructuredBuffer<byte> in my compute shader.

From what I've read, you can't. There is no `byte` data type in HLSL (nor CG, which is what unity uses). The example above is a standard vertex/fragment shader, for using compute shaders I would refer you to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40670427/3d-buffers-in-hlsl/40720900) on your other question. Augment it to your needs. As I have already written in a comment, if you do not want to use `int` for your `byte` data and thus waste 24 bits, you can punch 4 `bytes` into 1 `int` with bit shifting. The shifting operation should be available in shaders when using shader model above 4 (DX10.1 or something)

An example of how to do this is as follows:

```
//encoding on the cpu

int myInt = 0;
myInt += (int)myByte1;
myInt += (int)(myByte2 << 8);
myInt += (int)(myByte3 << 16);
myInt += (int)(myByte4 << 24);

//decoding on the gpu

myByte1 = myInt & 0xFF;
myByte2 = (myInt >> 8) & 0xFF;
myByte3 = (myInt >> 16) & 0xFF;
myByte4 = (myInt >> 24) & 0xFF;
```

Comment: I know how to use structured buffers ,and I know how to send ints to the GPU. I want to know how to send "byte"s to the GPU @xyLe_

Comment: there is no `byte` data type in HLSL nor in CG (which is what unity uses by default). in CG you could go with `char`, but can't you just go with `int`?

Comment: if you are really possessed with used space, then just pack 4 bytes into 1 int and use bit shifts

Comment: @None I've updated my answer